# How to force Gradle to pick up tests in `main`?

Tags: gradle

We have some of our tests in `main` (so they can be built into and run from a service). The latest Gradle defaults to not recognizing source in `main` as test code.

I thought I could use the Nebula Facets plugin but the following doesn't work around the problem, either:

```
facets {
  functionalTest {
    parentSourceSet = 'main'
    includeInCheckLifecycle = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is how to override `srcDirs`:

```
facets {
  functionalTest {
    includeInCheckLifecycle = false
  }
}

sourceSets {
  functionalTest {
    java {
      srcDirs = ["${projectDir}/src/main/java"]
    }
    resources {
      srcDirs = ["${projectDir}/src/main/resources"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to live with tests in `src/main/java`, then you do not need an extra source set.

Instead you need to configure a test task so that it uses the `main` source set classpath.

Here is an example to configure such a test task, using the Kotlin DSL and task configuration avoidance:

```
val mainTest = tasks.register<Test>("mainTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    description = "Run tests from main"
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["main"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.named("check").configure {
    dependsOn(mainTest)
}
```

Comment: Code would be helpful.